# Trying to create configurable product, error product id already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, error

When I try to create an configurable product I get the following error:

*Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "3941" already exist*

I can't find the problem. Creating a simple product does not have this problem. Is there a seperate auto_increment for configurable products? Any body any idea how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open the product by opening a random product and replacing the id in the url with 3941. And then try to delete this product and see what happens if you try to create a new configurable product. For example:

```
/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/3941/key/../
```